# Put value of column in a cell

Tags: pandas

my df is:

```
Ordinal     Timestamp                   Latitude Longitude  id_easy
1           2016-06-01T08:18:46.000Z    44.9484  7.7728     22
2           2016-06-01T08:28:05.000Z    44.9503  7.7748     22
3           2016-06-01T08:28:09.000Z    44.9503  7.7748     22
1           2016-06-01T06:31:05.000Z    45.0314  7.6181     16
```

I want to concentrate my values of "Longitude" and "Latitude" into one cell by same "id_easy" at a given "Timestamp". "Ordinal" is the number of times id_easy happened:

```
id_easy 22 - location [[long,lat],[long,lat],[long,lat],[long,lat]] - Timestamp from 8:00 to 9:00 (for the whole day)
```

desired output is:

```
id_easy  location                                                Timestamp
22       [[44.9484  7.7728],[44.9503  7.7748],[44.9503  7.7748]] 08:00-09:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of options here, but I'd probably use lambda.

```py
df['location'] = df.apply(lambda row: [row['Longitude'], row['Latitude']]), 
    axis=1)
```

Comment: TypeError: ('sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found', 'occurred at index (22, 0)') @Eva vW